# Github: Can you access the list of private repos that a user has shared with you using the personal token?

Tags: python, api, github, token, github-api

I want to make an automatic zip back up of the repos a user has shared with me using the github API. Since I'm only using this locally I thought it would be simpler to use the personal token.

For testing I have enabled all permissions on the token generation. Then used https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos#list-repositories-for-a-user.

```
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/vnd.github+json",
    "Authorization": f"token {githubPersonalToken}",
}
response = (requests.get(f"https://api.github.com/users/USER/repos", headers=headers)).json()
```

The problem is that I only get the list of public repo's which is not what I'm after.

Is the problem that I am using the wrong call OR that it is not possible with a personal token and I need to OAuth OR something else?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER - Turns out that if the repo is shared with you then you look under your own username to see them using user/repos no need to put in a username.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).